# Want to create multi scripts to access facebook api using access token but variable is undefined

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Currently I have two php scripts: index.php and upload.php

In my index.php I have created a session and saved the access token:

```
  // see if a existing session exists
  if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    // create new session from saved access_token
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

// validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
    $session = null;
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
// catch any exceptions
$session = null;
    }
}     

if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
    // no session exists

try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
        print_r( $ex );
            } catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
// handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
}

}

 // see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

      // save the session
            $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
         // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
           $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
```

In my other script: upload.php I am trying to make a facebook api but I am struggling to create a session. I did this:

```
         if ( isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
      // create FB session from Access Token
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

     // the rest of your code here...

      } else {
    // redirect back to index for login
     header( 'Location: index.php' );
       }
```

but it just redirects me back to index.php. I don't understand why because I did create the variable in index.php...

I also tried to use the GET method to fetch the code from my URL...

```
$token = $_GET['code'];

$session = new FacebookSession( $token );
```

But it says that the variable is undefined... even though "code" shows in my URL... I also did isset but it returned false.. so I am not sure at all why my variable is unset. Can someone please explain and help me out? I am new to php so have been spending all day on this and I am sure it's probably a small problem? I have retrieved userid from the URL before from another simple project of mine and never came across this problem... Thanks

Comment: Did you used `session_start()` in the top of your php file?

Comment: @Stefan Yes I did.. I also tried to echo the 'code' in index.php but I still get the error: undefined index. I've googled and looked at similar questions, but I don't understand and I don't know how to fix :S

Comment: Try to test if the sessions are working ok; something like invoking a URL: ` if($_GET['q'] == 'test_session') $_SESSION['test'] = 'ok'; else print_r($_SESSION['test']);`

Comment: The session should be working okay because I was able to retrieve user's profile data... :S 

Not sure where to put your code to test... and what is 'q'? Sorry I am new to php..

Comment: Try this in a new file: <?php session_start();

// index.php?q=test
if($_GET['q'] == 'test')
{
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'ok';
    die("Session set, reload page without ?q=test");
}
else
{
    print_r($_SESSION['test']);
}

?>

Comment: @Stefan I tried this in a new file but just got a syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\test.php on line 3

Comment: Yeah.. because of the anti-newline policy in the comments :-) Without the comment: <?php session_start();

if($_GET['q'] == 'test')
{
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'ok';
    die("Session set, reload page without ?q=test");
}
else
{
    print_r($_SESSION['test']);
}

?>

Comment: Oh right, sorry. Okay, I got this: Session set, reload page without ?q=test. So it works? Hmm no idea why for the facebook access token in the url it won't work.

Comment: Are you familiar with facebook api? I think I know what the problem is. Notice: Undefined index: code in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\upload.php on line 44. 

It's looking for the variable in my localhost url rather than the app url... but I don't know how to change this.. In my redirect URL in my other php script I have the app url..

Comment: If you reload the page without ?q=test then you can see if the session works. Should echo ok. I am familiar with the facebook api, but your problems seems to be in the sessions. (You where able to retrieve data via the API so that works)

Comment: Yes it does echo "ok". 

I've merged it all into one script now because I couldn't fix it. Do you think I could message you outside of SOF regarding facebook api? I am having so many problems and there doesn't seem to be much online on it :( if not, could you please have a look at my other questions? I am struggling with uploading a photo that has been saved on my sever. I managed to post a message on my wall though. Many thanks.

Comment: Keep the communication on SOF so also other people are able to learn from the questions and answers. If it still doesn't work I advice you to show a bit more of your files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57770/discussion-between-fondillusions-and-stefan).